# Tools, scripts for working with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, scripting

While working with DB, I find useful using some tools, that help me to solve DB problems.

Some of them are:

**1)** Insert generator

**2)** A tool that can execute a script on a list of DB's

**3)** Finding a text in stored procedures and functions.

**4)** DB Back up scripts

My question is, what are most useful tools, scripts(anything else), that help you to work with **SQL Server**?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I assume, there are no other tools for SQL Server 2008 or any other version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_professional_toolbelt/index.htm) has a collection of quite powerful tools for Sql Server.

Comment: $1,995$? Maybe I should add word "free" to my question?

Comment: @hgulyan: first, you didn't specify *free*, and second those Red-Gate tools *are* worth their price - every penny of it!

Comment: @marc_s, I didn't say that this answer isn't useful. It's really is and there're some free tools on this site too. All I was saying, that I can't afford that kind of tool. That's the only problem, but I'm surely interested in all tools, that are useful.

Comment: @hgulyan: OK, fair point. I'm always a bit surprised, though, how many software engineers (who make a living programming) are totally reluctant to spend a few dollars for a valuable tool that helps them save time and reduces their hassles....

Comment: @marc_s, I'd be happy to have this tool and some others, but I can't afford it by myself and my boss doesn't want to spent money on tools either.

Comment: @marc_s, at some places it is easier to get blood from a stone than get the software tools you need.  I worked at a place that upgraded all user PCs (a few hundred) from Windows 3.1 only because of Y2K (and it was in December 1999 when they upgraded).  I'm sure they would still be on win 3.1 if it weren't for Y2K.

Comment: @KM, we use ms access 97. How's that for you?

Comment: @KM:  oh I know - I have been fighting for four years before I finally got those tools - just imagine all those lost hours of work in those years......

Comment: @marc_s, I hope, I don't have to wait so much)))

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [SMSS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I have stored procedures that do the following:

system utilities:

- find and list every occurrence and info about a given column name or partial column name
- find and list every occurrence and info about a given object name or partial object name
- list out all the information for a given table, all columns, computed columns, column data types, nullability, defaults, identity, check constraints, index, pk, fk, triggers, and column comments.
- find every trigger, view, stored procedure, or function that contains a given string

business utilities:

I also make stored procedures that work with business info.  When working on an area of our application I'll make a procedure that displays out all the related info of a given thing.  I'll usually display all the info using multiple PRINTs and SELECTs for everything that can join to the given PK (not if there are thousands or rows though).  For example, one utiltiy would take a DoctorID as a parameter and list out all the doctor's info, offices that they work at, insurance they accept, etc.  I like to include the table names in the output so I can remember where the data comes from without looking at the code.  I also join in all the codes tables in these displays, so I'm not looking "A" but "Active (A)".  After working on a system for a while, I have loads of these utilities, which greatly helps when a support call comes up or you need to debug a problem, etc.  I usually build these as I develop, it is difficult to find time to go back and make them.